# ucontext across threads

Tags: linux, coroutine

Are contexts (the objects manipulated by functions in `ucontext.h`) allowed to be shared across threads? That is, can I `swapcontext` with the second argument being a context created in `makecontext` on another thread? A test program seems to show this working on Linux. I can't find documentation one way or the other on this, whereas Windows fibers appear to explicitly support such a use case. Is this safe and OK to do in general? Is it standard POSIX behavior that this should work?

Comment: Can you post your test program as well, here?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there was an NGPT - threading library for linux, which uses not a current 1:1 threading model (each user thread is the kernel thread or LWP), but a M:N threading model (several user threads corresponds to another, smaller number of kernel threads).

According to [ftp://ftp.uni-duisburg.de/Linux/NGPT/ngpt-0.9.4.tar.gz/ngpt-0.9.4/pth_sched.c:170 pth_scheduler](http://www.google.com/codesearch#yhcp39oOAbE/Linux/NGPT/ngpt-0.9.4.tar.gz%7CobzxKJeJGsA/ngpt-0.9.4/pth_sched.c&q=pth_mctx_switch&exact_package=ftp://ftp.uni-duisburg.de/Linux/NGPT/ngpt-0.9.4.tar.gz&type=cs&l=171) it was possible of moving user thread contexts between native (kernel) threads:

```
        /*
         * See if the thread is unbound...
         * Break out and schedule if so...
         */
        if (current->boundnative == 0)
            break;
        /*
         * See if the thread is bound to a different native thread...
         * Break out and schedule if not...
         */
        if (current->boundnative == this_sched->lastrannative)
            break;
```

To save and restore user threads, the ucontext can be used [ftp://ftp.uni-duisburg.de/Linux/NGPT/ngpt-0.9.4.tar.gz/ngpt-0.9.4/pth_mctx.c:64](http://www.google.com/codesearch#yhcp39oOAbE/Linux/NGPT/ngpt-0.9.4.tar.gz%7CobzxKJeJGsA/ngpt-0.9.4/pth_mctx.c&type=cs&l=64) and seems this was a preferred method (`mcsc`):

```
/*
 * save the current machine context
 */
#if PTH_MCTX_MTH(mcsc)
#define pth_mctx_save(mctx) \
        ( (mctx)->error = errno, \
          getcontext(&(mctx)->uc) )
#elif
....
/*
 * restore the current machine context
 * (at the location of the old context)
 */
#if PTH_MCTX_MTH(mcsc)
#define pth_mctx_restore(mctx) \
        ( errno = (mctx)->error, \
          (void)setcontext(&(mctx)->uc) )
#elif PTH_MCTX_MTH(sjlj)
...

#if PTH_MCTX_MTH(mcsc)

/*
 * VARIANT 1: THE STANDARDIZED SVR4/SUSv2 APPROACH
 *
 * This is the preferred variant, because it uses the standardized
 * SVR4/SUSv2 makecontext(2) and friends which is a facility intended
 * for user-space context switching. The thread creation therefore is
 * straight-foreward.
 */
```

So, even if NGPT is dead and unused, it selected *context() for switching user threads even between kernel threads. I assume, that using *context() family is safe enough on Linux.

There can be some problems when mixing ucontexts and other native threads library. I will consider a NPTL, which is standard linux native threading library since glibc 2.4. The main problem is THREAD_SELF - pointer to `struct pthread` of the current thread. TLS (Thread-local storage) also works via THREAD_SELF. The THREAD_SELF is usually stored on register ([r2 on powerpc](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/libc-alpha/2006-12/msg00085.html), `%gs` on x86, etc). get/setcontext might save and restore this register breaking internals of native pthread library (e.g. thread-local storage, thread identification, etc).

The glibc setcontext [will not save/restore `%gs` register](http://www.google.com/codesearch#xy1xtVWIKOQ/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2%7CXP6Z3zoy3dk/glibc-20090518/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/setcontext.S&q=setcontext&exact_package=ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2&type=cs&l=55) to be compatible with pthreads:

```
    /* Restore the FS segment register.  We don't touch the GS register
       since it is used for threads.  */
    movl    oFS(%eax), %ecx
    movw    %cx, %fs
```

You should check, does setcontext saves THREAD_SELF register on the architecture you are interested in. Also, your code can be not portable between OSes and `libc`s.

Comment: Not entirely satisfactory, but I guess it's the best info you can have around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/makecontext.3.html)

> In a System V-like environment, one
>   has the type ucontext_t defined in
>    and the four functions
>   getcontext(2), setcontext(2),
>   makecontext() and swapcontext() that
>   allow user-level context switching
>   between multiple threads of control
>   within a process.

Sounds like that's what it's for.

EDIT: although [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/browse_thread/thread/c29c8a84e16fdba9) seems to indicate that you shouldn't be mixing them.

Comment: No. This says about "threads of control", the threads which are saved and restored by *context(). It says nothing about mixing *context() functions and pthreads.

Comment: Is the [Solaris](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/browse_thread/thread/c29c8a84e16fdba9) discussion helpful? Why on earth do you want to do this anyway? Threading is slippery enough as it is without mixing up thread definitions.

Comment: Its not for me. Native threads can be enough to plain C, but not enough for 1) coroutines, e.g. in Go, etc 2) languages with green threads, e.g. Ruby/Python